# under what conditions does f'(c) exists

Tags: real-analysis

suppose p(x) is continuous on (a,c] and differentiable on (a,c)
suppose q(x) is continuous on [c,b) and differentiable on (c,b)

let  $$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&p(x) &&: a<x \le c\\
&q(x) &&: c<x<b
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

under what conditions on p and q does f'(c) exists

My attempt:

For $f'(c)$ to exists at $c$, $\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ should exist.
$$\implies \lim_{x\to c+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} $$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to c+}\dfrac{q(x)-p(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c-}\dfrac{p(x)-p(c)}{x-c} $$
since the limits are of the form $0/0$, I use l'hopital rule
$$\implies \lim_{x\to c+}q'(x)=\lim_{x\to c-}p'(x) $$

is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, you can't use Hospital's rule at $c$ because you don't know if $f'(c)$ exists.

You need continuity.

$p(c) = q(c)$

Then you don't have to mix your $p$ s and $q$ s in the limits.

$f'(c) = \lim_\limits{x\to c} \frac {f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \implies \lim_\limits{x\to c^-} \frac {p(x) - p(c)}{x-c} = \lim_\limits{x\to c^-} \frac {q(x) - q(c)}{x-c}$

$f'(c) = \lim_\limits{x\to c^-} p'(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to c^+} q'(x)$

Comment: should there be limits in the last statement. should it be p'(c)? @Doug M